# How to remove double quote in vector in R

Tags: r

I extract some data but there are some problems.
There are big data and here is some sample.
The data "energy" is

```
> energy

"XOM" "APA" "CVX" "DUK"
```

`XOM`, `APA`, `CVX`, `DUK` are all data.frame.

but if I select `XOM` like `energy[1]` then, it shows

```
"XOM"
```

I want to make

```
> energy 

XOM APA CVX DUK
```

Because *I want to change column names of `XOM`, `APA`, `CVX`, `DUK` with `colnames()`.*

I make for loop function, like this...

```
for (i in length(energy) ) {
  colnames(energy[i]) = c('a','b','c','d', ..... )
}
```

But it doesn't work and also I tried

```
for (i in length(energy) ) {
  colnames(get(energy[i])) = c('a','b','c','d', ..... )
}
```

but I got errors.

Please help me and really sorry about my poor English skills

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: I'm not trying to change energy... I want to change colnames of XOM, APA, CVX, DUK. But those are in Energy vector

Comment: I really appreciated!! Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `XOM`, `APA`, `CVX` and `DUK` are 4 `data.frame`s with 5 columns.

```
XOM <- APA <- CVX <- DUK <- head(iris)
energy <- c("XOM", "APA", "CVX", "DUK")

XOM

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

You can use `mget()` and `lapply()` to reset their column names at the same time.

```
list2env(lapply(mget(energy), setNames, c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")), .GlobalEnv)
```

Check your workspace:

```
XOM

#     A   B   C   D      E
# 1 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
# 2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
# 3 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
# 4 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
# 5 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
# 6 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` to rename all of the columns in the dataframes in your list:

```
new_names <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ....)
energy <- lapply(names(energy), function(x) setNames(energy[[x]], new_names))
```

Here's an example:

```
energy <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)
names(energy)[1] <- '"XOM"'
names(energy)[2] <- '"APA"'
names(energy)[3] <- '"CVX"'
names(energy)[4] <- '"DUK"'

new_names <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'nice', 'cars')
energy <- lapply(names(energy), function(x) setNames(energy[[x]], new_names))
```

Which gives us:

```
> head(energy[[1]])
                     a b   c   d nice  cars    NA NA NA NA NA
Mazda RX4         21.0 6 160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1  4  4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0 6 160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1  4  4
Datsun 710        22.8 4 108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1  4  1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4 6 258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0  3  1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7 8 360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0  3  2
Valiant           18.1 6 225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0  3  1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. First. I extract data with library but it saves vector not list... this is main problems. So if I make list(energy) then [1] "XOM" "APA" "CVX" "DUK" not divided. If i have more then 4 dataframe in Energy, how to deal with?